# How would I go about getting the full commit hash in Dulwich?

Tags: python, dulwich

I would like to get the behavior of `git show -s --format=%H` in Dulwich; i.e. getting the *full commit hash* pointed to by `HEAD`. However, as it turns out the [`porcelain.show()` function](https://dulwich.io/docs/api/dulwich.porcelain.html#dulwich.porcelain.show) behaves pretty much like `git show` but doesn't seem to know any additional options like the Git CLI.

I am not surprised, given [`porcelain.describe()`](https://dulwich.io/docs/api/dulwich.porcelain.html#dulwich.porcelain.describe) behaves similarly. But what alternative means do I have with Dulwich to see the *full* commit hash of `HEAD`?

For the abbreviated - albeit hardcoded to 7 characters (!) - hash I can use the aforementioned `porcelain.describe()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By consulting [the code for `porcelain.describe()`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/f25a86e97ba199716969d136237a5e1814fb0b79/dulwich/porcelain.py#L1988) we can pull the pieces together.

1. `open_repo_closing` offers a nice context manager for the [`dulwich.repo.BaseRepo` class](https://dulwich.io/docs/api/dulwich.repo.html#dulwich.repo.BaseRepo), with `contextlib.closing` behavior
2. [`BaseRepo.head()`](https://dulwich.io/docs/api/dulwich.repo.html#dulwich.repo.BaseRepo.head) contains the information as `bytes`

A minimal implementation could look like this:

```
def get_latest_hash(repo):
    from dulwich.porcelain import open_repo_closing
    with open_repo_closing(repo) as r:
        return r.head().decode("ascii")
```

Simpler than I initially expected.